# Ruby implementation of Soundex algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ruby

I'm new to Ruby. I normally sling code in C#. What could I do to make this simple Soundex class more Rubyesque?

```
class Surname
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(input)
    @value = input
  end

  def soundex
    result = ''
    @value.chars.drop(1).each do |s|
      number = soundex_value(s).to_s
      result &lt;&lt; number unless result[-1,1] == number
    end
    @value.chars.first &lt;&lt; result.ljust(3,'0')
  end

  def soundex_value(s)
    case s
    when /[bfpv]/
      1
    when /[cgjkqsxz]/ 
      2
    when /[dt]/ 
      3
    when /l/ 
      4
    when /[mn]/ 
      5
    when /r/ 
      6
    else ''
    end
  end
end

def print_name(input)
  surname = Surname.new(input)
  puts(surname.value + ' => ' + surname.soundex)
end

['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Brown'].each do |s|
  print_name s
end
```

The output is:

```
Smith => S530
Johnson => J525
Williams => W452
Jones => J520
Brown => B650
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your request, your code converted to the Ruby way perhaps would be as follows.

A small point: in our output, in the Ruby world, we would avoid the **=>** [fat comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fat_comma&oldid=546331414) which Rubyists (at least in the English-speaking world) call a 'hash-rocket' because:

- It reads like Ruby's ([older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004158/is-hash-rocket-deprecated)) hash accessing syntax.
- In Ruby language documentation (e.g., see [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html)), the similar **#=>**, comprising a hash to introduce a comment, followed by a hash-rocket (presumably, this gave us the name), shows us the result (or value) of an *individual* line of code—the two meanings conflict.

BTW, we also would avoid **->**, dash-greater-than, which in Ruby (syntax) generates a lambda.

```
class Soundex < String
  IGNORED_BEGINNING_LENGTH = 1
  MINIMUM_LENGTH = 3

  CASES = [ # Keep order.
    /[bfpv]/,
    /[cgjkqsxz]/,
    /[dt]/,
    /l/,
    /[mn]/,
    /r/,
  ]
  CASES_LENGTH = CASES.length

  def initialize(surname)
    a = surname.split ''
    kept    = a.take(IGNORED_BEGINNING_LENGTH).join ''
    indices = a.drop(IGNORED_BEGINNING_LENGTH).map do |e|
      (0...CASES_LENGTH).detect{|i| e =~ (CASES.at i)}
    end.compact
# Adjust to one-based notation; collapse repetition; right-pad with zeros.
    digits = indices.map(&:succ).join('').squeeze.ljust MINIMUM_LENGTH, '0'
    super kept + digits
  end

  def self.show(s) "#{s}: #{new s}" end
end

names = %w[Smith Johnson Williams Jones Brown Atchison]
names.each{|s| puts Soundex.show s}
```

gives the results

```
Smith: S530
Johnson: J525
Williams: W452
Jones: J520
Brown: B650
Atchison: A325
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll study what you did here and fill in some holes in my Ruby knowledge.

Comment: Rather than thanking me, would you consider voting up or accepting my answer? :)

Comment: I believe that `=>` is known as a “hashrocket” because it’s used in hashes (associative arrays), not because it’s associated with the number sign. And there’s nothing wrong with using it in sample output IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: install RSpec and write some tests if you haven't already. That will make sure you don't break anything while refactoring. (And then do all development test-first if you don't already.) Also, there are existing Ruby Soundex implementations. You might want to use one instead of writing your own.

For the rest of it:

- I think your implementation is incorrect! Try this: does "Atchison" yield "A322"? It should.
- Why do you need a separate class for `Surname`? It may make sense to have a module with the Soundex algorithm that either gets mixed into Strings as necessary or calls the method with function syntax (e.g. `Soundex::encode last_name`). I'm not sure.
- If you *do* need a separate class for `Surname`, perhaps it should extend `String`, or delegate to its String member, so that you can easily call String methods on it. But I think a plain old String with a module included would work better.
- `@value` seems like a nondescriptive name. Perhaps `@name` or something?
- You may not need the `attr_accessor`, since `@surname.to_s` would be more idiomatic than `@surname.value`.
- Instead of that `@value.chars.drop(1).each` block, you may want to use `map`.
- Regular expressions may not be the right thing for the `case` expression; you may want `when 'b', 'p'` instead. Or you may want to drop the `case` entirely and have a hash: `{'b' => 1, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 3, 'f' => 1, ... }`. Or I seem to recall that `Array#assoc` might be useful here...
- Since you're calling `to_s` on `soundex_value` the only time you use it, maybe it should just return a string in the first place.

Good luck! I hope these suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Yes, very helpful. RSpec is an excellent suggestion, as is map. I am blind to those features I don't know exist. :)

Comment: You are also correct that there is a bug in my algorithm.